# How to keep the delimiters with regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to keep the delimiters with regex ?

I've tried the following

```
string str = "user1;user2;user3;user4";

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w;");    

            string[] splites = regex.Split(str);
            foreach (string match in splites)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

output :

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

I want to be as follows But do not be:

output :

```
user1;
user2;
user3;
user4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) seems more appropriate:

```
string str = "user1;user2;user3;user4";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\w+;?");
foreach (var match in re.Matches(str)) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[Demo run](http://ideone.com/TMDgru)

---

Alternatively you can use lookbehind assertion:

```
string str = "user1;user2;user3;user4";
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=;)");
foreach (var match in re.Split(str)) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[Demo run](http://ideone.com/zxyKgz)

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing this like this

```
        string str = "user1;user2;user3;user4";
        MatchCollection matchs= Regex.Matches(str, @"[\w]+;?");
        foreach (Match m in matchs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
```